# How to enumerate a continuous group of rows based on order in result of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to get a column like the *desired_output* column below and have tried functions like DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER, but can't seem to get the right combination here. I don't have a key to identify the "transition" between **continuous groups**.

So each time it hits a new group per id_key, regardless of if it already hit that group before (ordered by sequence) I'd like to start a new "transition"

Ultimately the goal is to get something like the MIN and MAX *sequence* per *desired_output* which I was just going to do with GROUP BY. I was able to accomplish this using a complex query of LEAD/LAG/JOINS, but want to see if anyone knows of a DENSE_RANK-like function (or way to use DENSE_RANK) that would give the *desired_output* below (to paint the full picture).

Thanks !

```
id_key      sequence    group       desired_output          
1           1           A           1
1           2           A           1
1           3           B           2
1           4           B           2
1           5           B           2
1           6           B           2
1           7           C           3
1           8           C           3
1           9           C           3
1           10          B           4
1           11          B           4
1           12          B           4
1           13          C           5
1           14          C           5
2           15          A           1
2           16          A           1
2           17          B           2
2           18          B           2
2           19          C           3
2           20          C           3
2           21          B           4
2           22          C           5
2           23          C           5
2           24          C           5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_key, sequence, [group],
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY id_key 
                       ORDER BY sequence) + 1 AS desired_output
FROM (
  SELECT id_key, sequence, [group],
         IIF(LAG([group]) OVER (PARTITION BY id_key 
                                ORDER BY sequence) <> [group], 1, 0) AS flag
  FROM mytable) AS t
ORDER BY sequence
```

`flag` field flags any changes in `[group]` column within each `id_key` partition. The outer query uses `flag` field to calculate a *running total*, so as to account for all `[group]` changes in each `id_key` partition.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Dense_Rank() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/tsql-dense-rank-function.aspx) is the correct way of solving this requirement I guess.
What you might have missed can be the Partition By clause which can be used in window functions.

Here is a Select query that might help

```
--create table myrows (id_key int, [sequence] int, [group] varchar(3))
/*
insert into myrows select   1   ,   1   ,'A'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   2   ,'A'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   3   ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   4   ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   5   ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   6   ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   7   ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   8   ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   9   ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   10  ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   11  ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   12  ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   13  ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   1   ,   14  ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   15  ,'A'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   16  ,'A'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   17  ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   18  ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   19  ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   20  ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   21  ,'B'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   22  ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   23  ,'C'    
insert into myrows select   2   ,   24  ,'C'    
*/

select *, 
    DENSE_RANK() over (partition by id_key order by [group]) desired_output
from myrows
```

Comment: doesn't account for the transition of groups at sequence = 21... which is where i am :-)

Comment: OK, I see.. I think Giorgos solution works fine with SQL Server  LAG() function used for defining gaps or catching data changes in a sequence